# NetSuite: How do I populate a custom transaction field with the ship-to custom address field

Tags: netsuite

In NetSuite, how do I populate a custom transaction field

```
(custbody_site_no_shipto)
```

on a transaction (for example, a Sales Order) with a custom address field

```
(custrecord_site_no)
```

for the Ship-To Address selected (under the Shipping tab)?

```
 Custom transaction field: custbody_site_no_shipto
 (Menu: Customization > Lists, Records, & Fields > Transaction Body   Fields – Display Type is Inline Text).

 Custom address field: custrecord_site_no
 (Menu: Customization > Lists, Records, & Fields > Other Custom Fields –    Checked Apply To All Custom Address Forms).
```

Comment: What is the data type for 'custbody_site_no_shipto'? Also, tell me more about the Ship-To-Address field. What is its type?

Comment: Both the custom fields are Free-Form Text. Did that answer your question?

Comment: You would typically set up this kind of relationship using Sourcing on your `custbody_site_no_shipto` definition. You would set the *Source List* to *Shipping Address* and the *Source From* to your `custrecord_site_no`. Unfortunately, *Shipping Address* is not an option, only *Ship To*, which points to the Contact, not the Address.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, you would configure the sourcing of the custom field on the 'Sourcing and Filtering'. 

However, shipping address is not included the 'Source List'. 

So to cater that requirements, you might only do automation/customization either by SuiteFlow or SuiteScript (Client Side or User Event script).


And looking to your requirements, it seems you can only do this using after submit user event script. It is because the "Address" you wanted to access is a subrecord and not all APIs for it can be used on client side script. I have example below:

```
    var recSO = nlapiLoadRecord('salesorder', 34826,
        {
            recordmode : 'dynamic'
        });//34826 is the internal id of SO
    var recSubAddress = recSO.viewSubrecord('shippingaddress');//Ship To field id
    var stSiteN0 = recSubAddress.getFieldValue('custrecord_site_no');

    recSO.setFieldValue('custbody_site_no_shipto', stSiteN0);
    var stRecId = nlapiSubmitRecord(recSO);
```

Comment: Agreed. I am looking into creating a SuiteScript and then reference it in a Workflow, but I do not see how to get the ship-to address custom field.

Comment: Can you give me the exact use case of your requirements? I might help you if I can get exactly what you need.

Comment: When creating a transaction, like a Sales Order, the user selects a Ship-To address.  I would like to populate the custom transaction field with the custom value from the ship-to address selected (field names listed in original question). I have already added the custom transaction field to the screen (but haven't figured out how to populate it yet).

Comment: Based on your requirements, you can't do it on the apply after the user selects shipping address. This can only be done on server side.

Comment: Use aftersubmit user event script. I have example above.

Answer (score 0):

The script below works and was implemented as a User Event Script.

```
function userEventBeforeSubmit(type) {
 var shipadd = nlapiGetFieldValue('shipaddresslist');
 var customer = nlapiGetFieldValue('entity');

 var record = nlapiLoadRecord('customer', customer,{recordmode: 'dynamic'});
 var linenum = record.findLineItemValue('addressbook', 'internalid', shipadd);


 record.selectLineItem('addressbook', linenum);
 var subrecord = record.viewCurrentLineItemSubrecord('addressbook', 'addressbookaddress');
 var customfield1 = subrecord.getFieldValue('custrecord_site_no'); 
 nlapiSetFieldValue('custbody_site_no_shipto', customfield1);
}
```